# Microsoft Indexing Service Catalog Location

Tags: windows, indexing, service

I have microsoft indexing service setup on a Windows 2008 server.  The hard drive is getting full and I need to move the catalog to a shared volume but I get an error when trying to create a catalog on a file share.  NOTE: I'm not talking about indexing files on a shared volume.  I'm talking about locating the catalog files on a shared volume.

Does anyone know if this is possible?